# Why does my voltage tester show power but my outlets don't work?

Tags: electrical

I removed the light fixture (which was not working due to old age-so I thought) to install LED lights. I thought it was the fixture or bad connection. Having to wait for my LEDs to come in I was going to connect wires back up to have power to the garage door. Well, in short I have power according to hot wire tester all the way to outlet but door opener will not work. I had extra 15A outlet so, I replaced it and still no go.  FYI- breaker shuts off power to garage and to the kitchen and laundry room lights.

Comment: What sort of tester? Simple voltage testers aren't always reliable--they may indicate phantom voltage. I'd pick up an inexpensive multimeter and read actual voltage.

Comment: "Current" is not a cooler way to say "voltage", in the same way that "torque" is not a cooler way to say "horsepower".  Those voltage testers only test for safety as in "careful, this might zap you"... they are not a whole-system diagnostic. In reality, power flows in loops - it doesn't work for power to come from the panel, go through the switch to the lamp then ??? magic happens.  Power must also make it back from the lamp to the panel.  There's a loop.